# How to get output for the following code?

Tags: java, static

I tried to get the output for this code but I am getting error, when compiling the program and the error is

> illegal start of expression

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        static int t = 5;

        for(int i = 0;i<2; i++){
            t += i;
        }

        System.out.println (t);
    }
}
}
```

and one more question can we write static variable inside static method and can we change static value? and please give any exact reason...

Comment: You have just got the 1's complement of the ideal way of posting question.

Comment: I wonder how [such](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21644312/revisions) suggested edits get approved.

Comment: @devnull: Wow! Proof that rules just force alterations to a scheme. Makes me even more curious how some edits I suggest get *denied*!

Comment: i didn't get you  @ Rohit Jain

Comment: Never mind @user3164190

Comment: @user3164190 That comment is now deprecated.

Comment: Is this even the same code anymore? Looks like it was ALMOST edited into working condition.

Comment: @leigero Nope. It's the same. You can always see the edit history.

Comment: How is it that folks get rep for editing what is absolutely style choices?  @BoristheSpider took out spaces that are w/o doubt legit, and actually created a format worse than op's and gets rep for it. Just look at the `for` loop format! It's clear an intentional style choice was purposefully edited out for the sake of rep leaving the op looking sub-par; awesome!!

Comment: @RohitJain, Boris : Pleas disregard previous comment, I now know how it is that you do not get rep.  I still stand behind what my complaint was about which was needless editing, *especially* over what is no more than style choices.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Which edit are you talking about? And you only get reps for editing till you have 2000 reps yourself, after which you don't.

Comment: @BobbyDigital like the [new edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21644312/revisions) that just came in? In any case, we should probably delete all the conversation comments from the post - this isn't where they belong.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a `static` local variable. That's one issue. Also, you've an extra closing parenthesis.

Comment: i think mr. rohit jain gave correct answer to me and all other making controversy..

Answer (score 1):

In method you can not use `static` variables. Use the same variable without `static`.

Answer (score 1):

`static` variable cannot  be declared as a local variable.

```
    static int t = 5;
     public static void main(String[] args) {
//      static int t = 5; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            t += i;
        }
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider I mean global variable